# SOAP service in AEM 6.2

Tags: soap, jetty, cxf, jax-ws, aem

I'm trying to create a SOAP service in AEM 6.2 (the client cant make a REST call). Right now its up and works, the problem is when we redeploy or the AEM instance is reset... then the port of the service gets locked. Error on "create()".

```
final JaxWsServerFactoryBean jaxWsServerFactoryBean = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
jaxWsServerFactoryBean.setServiceClass(getWebServiceClass());
jaxWsServerFactoryBean.setAddress(this.webServiceAddress);
jaxWsServerFactoryBean.setServiceBean(this);
jaxWsServerFactoryBean.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
jaxWsServerFactoryBean.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());

server = jaxWsServerFactoryBean.create();

*ERROR* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine Could not start Jetty server on port 4,517: Address already in use: bind
```

The first time I deploy works fine but then I have to change port for each redeploy... I'm closing the server if exists before that create, and if I call "isStarted()" it says false.

```
server.getDestination().shutdown();
server.stop();
server.destroy();
```

Really stuck for days on this, thank you for your help.

Comment: Not an answer but that is one stubborn service consumer who wants to use only soap.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm currently stuck with this exact problem in a JUnit test case scenario where the port also stays locked and further unit tests classes cannot run in the same JVM session.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a OSGI bundle and create your soap service inside the bundle.

```
@Activate
public void activate(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
   ... start your soap service
}

@Deactivate
public void deactivate() throws Exception {
   ... stop your soap service
}
```

Now you can restart your soap service by restarting the bundle. here is reference how to create a OSGI bundle. http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/create-osgi-bundle-in-aem/

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Actually I create the soap service inside an OSGI bundle and that shutdown() stop() and destroy() are in deactivate(). The problem is that the port gets locked so on restarts or redeploys it can't be used again. The soap service is started in an independent Jetty on that address so AEM or bundle restarts do nothing.